# Flexbox и мой пример

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как сделать чтобы логотип был на месте, а шапка в правой стороне?

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.flex-container ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.list {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 5px 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="flex-container">
    <img class="logo" src="android.png">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="list" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="list" href="#">Company</a></li>
      <li><a class="list" href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a class="list" href="#">Price</a></li>
      <li><a class="list" href="#">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a class="list" href="#">Order</a></li>
      <li><a class="list" href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Вроде бы и указал, что `flex-container` должен быть `row`, слева направо находится `row` — строка (значение по умолчанию);

А именно `flex-container ul (flex-end)` то есть по правую сторону контент должен находиться, но всё равно не получается.

Как сейчас:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как надо:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так. Задай контейнеру

`justify-content: space-between;`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.flex-container ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.list {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 5px 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="flex-container">
    <img class="logo" src="android.png">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="list" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="list" href="#">Company</a></li>
      <li><a class="list" href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a class="list" href="#">Price</a></li>
      <li><a class="list" href="#">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a class="list" href="#">Order</a></li>
      <li><a class="list" href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Объясните почему вы написали: В * {padding: 0, margin: 0}?, а так же почему вы написали в html, body{ ширину 100% и высоту 100%?

Comment: Что объяснить???

Comment: А так же что такое *?

Comment: Потому что, по умолчанию у всех элементов есть `padding 4px, margin 4px`... Я всегда их сбрасываю... Привычка...  А `width: 100%;
  height: 100%;`  потому что у `body` по умолчанию `height: 0;` А у `html height: 4px;` Так что это привычка

Comment: Надеюсь внятно объяснил

Answer (score 2):

Есть такое свойство justify-content: space-between;

```
.flex-container { display: flex; justify-content: space-between;}
```

Если нужно сделать логотип фиксированным слева, а для меню использовать всё оставшееся пространство

```
.flex-container { display: flex;}
.flex-container > ul {display: flex; flex:1; justify-content: flex-end;}
```

Comment: И на кой я ответ писал)))))

Comment: Что такое .flex-container > ul {display: flex; flex:1; justify-content: flex-end;}, почему здесь вы поставили знак больше? Как это работает?

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван
Знак ">" - Синтаксис CSS - дочерний тег ul
Так как это меню - то я подумал, что внутри его будут ещё списки